# Unable to start device X11cairo in R on Mac 10.10

Tags: r, macos, x11

I try to use X11 to do the plots

```
X11( width=width*mag , height=height*mag , type="cairo" , ... )
```

but something weird happened.

> ** Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  : 
>   **unable to start device X11cairo** In addition: Warning message: In X11(width = width * mag, height = height * mag, type = "cairo",  :
>   **unable to open connection to X11 display** ''**

And when I use `capabilities()` to see whether X11 works, it shows `FALSE`

Can anyone tell me what I should do?

Comment: Have you defined your `DISPLAY` environment variable? Have you installed X11? OSX no longer ships with X11, AFAIK. My suggestion would be to install `XQuartz`